# Border image and how does it work

Tags: css

I hope you guys help me. I am really new to web designing and im having a hard time configuring how does border image work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaMUi.png)s://i.stack.imgur.com/RKyHZ.jpg

Comment: What is your question? Please, [edit] your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask a _specific_ question.

Comment: how can i use the image as a border image of my link.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to help without seeing the relevant HTML and CSS for your project, but have you checked the [border-image documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) on the Mozilla Developer Network? You could also read this [CSS-Tricks article on border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) for examples of how it works and a quick demo.

The syntax is `border-image: image-source | height | width | repeat`. Note that some browsers may require `border-style` (or the `border` shorthand) to be set as well.

```css
#example {
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  /* using linear-gradient() rather than a url() to avoid hotlinking */
  border-image: linear-gradient(teal, lime) 5 5 stretch;
}
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```